# elementor page builder applying border to images

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am new to wordpress

I am using elementor page builder in Wordpress, and when I select any image it comes with a border. even when I am making the border for image as 'none' still it is not going away

[image]

Here is the the CSS code which is getting applied as border style solid! 
My question is why this bug? and if I have to override it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by accessing the global theme style option in the elementor page builder.
Over there just go to Image Option and make the border option "none" this resolved the problem as it was a global CSS applied to entire website.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
body.elementor-kit-99
img {
border-style: none;
}
```

Copy and paste this in your theme custom CSS area